# Elastic search convert geohash_grid key to lat lon

Tags: elasticsearch

Using geohash_grid aggs in elasticsearch return this result:

```
"aggregations": {
  "Geo-hash": {
     "buckets": [
        {
           "key": "gcw05r6xz7cb",
           "doc_count": 305
        },
        {
           "key": "gcw2hzkpf7b8",
           "doc_count": 12
        }
     ]
  }
```

}

1)The key represent the center point of cell?

2)How to convert this key to lat lon? - I found some plugins is there anyway to avoid using plugins (not support all version , needs maintenance,etc.) and query directly geo ponts from elasticsearch?

Comment: You ever figure this out?

Comment: @User1234 Did you try using "geo point" type in elasticsearch?

Comment: @SanuraHettiarachchi  of course - in order to run the geohash_grid the field must be a geo point. the question is about how to parse geohash_grid result keys into lat.lon values.

Comment: @JMK I have spoke with one of elasticsearch developers ,  as i mentioned in my answer there is not ES build-in solution in current release version (2.3.3) - but in future versions maybe in Elastic 5 the will implement build-in solution. Anyway there is a nice workaround you can use

Comment: Found this link which nicely summarizes the idea and how it is done.  Just need to find a similar library for your language. https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/geohash.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way as i described in my question is to use one of many plugins a cross the web, [as this one](https://github.com/davidmoten/geo)

Any way if your data-set and cardinality is not too large you can use top hits aggs as sub aggs and then extract the geo-point field from the document.
That can be very expensive operation, use it wisely on small data-sets :)

```
   {
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "geo": {
      "geohash_grid": {
        "field": "locationField",
        "precision": 3
      }
      ,
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "top_hits": {
        "size": 1
      }
    }
  }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question:

1. The geohashes in the key represent an area. Please read this for more details about geohashes:
   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/geohashes.html
2. From the last section in this elasticsearch documentation about geohash grid aggregation, you need a library to convert a geohash into the equivalent bounding box or central point.
   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/geohash-grid-agg.html#geohash-grid-agg

You may explore Geo Bounds Aggregation to perform similar job, but I prefer convert it at client side.